# CSP Image Base64 not loading with proper server configuration

Tags: linux, nginx, server, base64, content-security-policy

Yes, another question about the CSP not loading a base64 image BUT I have researched a lot and can't find the solution. I have tried every configuration I've founded and still doesn't works.

So, what I'm trying is to load an Base64 image via Javascript.

```
var dataString = jQuery('#signature').jSignature('getData');
JQuery('#sig').append("<img class='imported' src='" + dataString + "'></img>");
```

As you can see it's not a big deal appending the base64 image (in localhost it works).

Then, searching about the CSP I found that the correct configuration to avoid the CSP with the Base64 Images is (and this is how I have the configuration):

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:";
```

I have no problem with the font base64 but with the images it always throws this error:

```
Refused to load the image 'data:image/png;base64,...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Any ideas will be really appreciated, I really have no idea what is happening.

Comment: Check to make sure the document doesn’t have 'meta http-equiv="content-security-policy"' with a different policy. Also use the Network pane in browser devtools to examine the Content-Security-Policy that the browser is receiving.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, I have already done that with curl, the network pane and it's the same as in my configuration file. Also I have checked if the isn't another csp meta tag and there isn't. 

And I moved the img-src to the begginig of the headers configuration with no result.

Comment: This is strange. Have you tried removing `default-src 'self'` from your CSP just to see if the `img-src` is being picked up then?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried as @Phonolog said. I have tried creating a plugin to support image url in `importData` rather than `data-url-formatted`.
Please check [this post](https://rinoreji.github.io/blog/a-plugin-for-jsignature-to-support-image-from-an-url) and see if it helps.

- Create a jSignature plugin which sets the img `src` to the signature url.
- inject the plugin
- on `importData` remember to pass the plugin identifier

This way you can remove the `data:` from the csp header and self should be enough (`img-src 'self'`)